# How to see the JMS listener port status without websphere administration console

Tags: java

How to see the JMS listener port status without websphere administration console in AIX server from backend ? I can find while application start up in SystemOut.log

Comment: You mean TCP/UDP port? Try netstat and/or lsof.

Comment: The JMS listener port name for instance myjms